# PhoneGAP, Cordova : Modifying Android project to load external URL

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying my hands on Cordova and phonegap. From the tutorials available, I was able to create a cordova app from command-line, and add android platform to it via the below mentioned commands. I then imported the android project in Android studio. As phonegap takes html, css content, I modified index.html to load an external URL, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? How can I point the application to load external URL? There were many other suggestions as I saw, but none of them even have the data I do. Thank you.

**Also, when I changed in config.xml the file from index.html to URL, it opened a chrome instance instead of opening it in the app.**

Commands :

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cordova platform add android --save
cordova build
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

Added the below line in index.html, but that didn't work either :

```
    <script>window.location.href="URL_I_AM_TRYING_TO_OPEN"</script>
```

config.xml :

```
// Trying to open google.com
  <content src="http://www.google.com" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
```

How can I load an external URL in the app itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What `allow-intent` tag does it to open the schemes/urls you put on the href property on a system app that can handle that scheme, so right now your `<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />` is opening chrome with google url.

The tag you need isn't `allow-intent`, it's `allow-navigation`

Add
`<allow-navigation href="http://www.google.com" />` to only allow navigation inside your app to google.com and the rest of urls open in chrome, or add `<allow-navigation href="*" />` to allow navigation to any website inside your app